# The number of times a custom event happened is not being updated on my dashboard

Tags: branch.io

I've been able to distinguish between the live build and the test build on my Android app. Everything works perfectly on the test version. I can see the live events and when I go and see the number of clicks for an event, that gets updated too. However, on the live build of my app, I can see the live events but the number of clicks is not being updated. All the events still show empty analytics. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Amruta from [Branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

Based on your description it looks like your App is still using the test key. If your App has both the Live and Test key added to the Manifest, and you have the debug mode enabled, your App will continue using the Test key. You should make sure that your App is using the Live key.

You can ensure that your app is using the Live key by using a Branch link from the Live version of your App. On clicking on the link, the link parameters received in the callback should have the parameter '+clicked_branch_link: true'.

If the parameter 'clicked_branch_link' is set to false it means that your App is still using the test key.

If you still continue to face issues, I would suggest writing to `integrations@branch.io` and they can help you resolve any issues you are facing.